# Insert List of Dictionary into Cassandra using Python

Tags: python, cassandra

i have tried to used the following method to insert my list of dictionary into cassandra but it does not work:

```
query = "INSERT INTO Roadworks5 (EventID,StartDate,EndDate,SvcDept,RoadName,Other) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
prepared = session.prepare(query)

for item in Road_works:
    session.execute(prepared,(item['EventID'],item['StartDate'],
                          item['EndDate'],item['SvcDept'],
                          item['RoadName'],item['Other']))
```

Below is the sample of the list of dictionary:

```
[{'EventID': 'RMAPP-202011-0214', 'StartDate': '2020-11-18', 'EndDate': '2021-06-30', 'SvcDept': 'PRIVATE', 'RoadName': 'ADAM ROAD', 'Other': 'For details'}
{'EventID': 'RMAPP-202008-1050', 'StartDate': '2020-08-31', 'EndDate': '2021-08-30', 'SvcDept': 'PRIVATE', 'RoadName': 'ADAM ROAD', 'Other': 'For details'}]
```

**can anyone help me with this.**

edited to update the error - the system go into infinite loop :
[image]

In addition, I have prepared individual lists but below is the error.

```
session.execute(prepared,(EventIDList,StartDateList,EndDateList,SvcDeptList,RoadNameList,OtherList))
```

> session.execute(prepared,(EventIDList,StartDateList,EndDateList,SvcDeptList,RoadNameList,OtherList))
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> session.execute(prepared,(EventIDList,StartDateList,EndDateList,SvcDeptList,RoadNameList,OtherList))
> File "cassandra\cluster.py", line 2618, in cassandra.cluster.Session.execute
> File "cassandra\cluster.py", line 2661, in cassandra.cluster.Session.execute_async
> File "cassandra\cluster.py", line 2864, in cassandra.cluster.Session._create_response_future
> File "cassandra\query.py", line 500, in cassandra.query.PreparedStatement.bind
> File "cassandra\query.py", line 626, in cassandra.query.BoundStatement.bind
> File "cassandra\cqltypes.py", line 771, in cassandra.cqltypes.UTF8Type.serialize
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'

added schema of table:
[image]

Comment: provide the error, or something like that shows what doesn't work

Comment: updated the error

Comment: sorry, can you show the schema of the table as well?

Comment: added the schema for reference

Comment: your code works just fine for me.  I'm confused by incosistency in naming of the variables in this piece: `session.execute(prepared,(EventIDList,StartDateList,EndDateList,SvcDeptList,RoadNameList,OtherList))` - I suspect that you're trying to pass lists of events, start dates, etc., not a strings

Comment: yes it works 2 records, however, my python script would not end when i ran the full list with 8000 records

Comment: Most probably because you use sync api